# ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I can't understand why the destroy method doesn't work only in just one class.
That's the code:

```
# DELETE /routes/1
  # DELETE /routes/1.json
  def destroy
    @route.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to routes_url, notice: 'Route was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
 end
```

I also tried this:

```
def destroy
  @route = Route.find(params[:id])
    if @route.destroy
      @route.destroy
    end 
     redirect_to routes_url
end
```

but with the same result.
Can you help me? thanks

EDIT.

this is the full error.

```
Started DELETE "/routes/10" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-22 18:24:24 +0200
Processing by RoutesController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"XP84FdlatYqkyB31qi872vNSo2aQjmkjKFlvjCnmsbr5M7nL11eo/QF+mlantF+CgLvag6leu4k4dGj8SMSOog==", "id"=>"10"}
  Route Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "routes".* FROM "routes" WHERE "routes"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Reservation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."route_id" = ?  [["route_id", 10]]
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 63ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed (ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed):
  app/controllers/routes_controller.rb:60:in `destroy'


  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (12.3ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (49.7ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.6ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (33.4ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.5ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.8ms)
  Rendered /home/railsuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2/gems/web-console-2.2.1/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (67.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you explain **doesn't work**?

Comment: destroy! might show a useful stacktrace.

Comment: sorry, I added the full error code

Comment: can you add model code? validations, etc

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of there being a dependency issue based on this:

```
Reservation Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "reservations".* FROM "reservations" WHERE "reservations"."route_id" = ?  [["route_id", 10]]
```

Do you have any validations or restrictions on that relationship?

Also, this portion:

```
if @route.destroy
  @route.destroy
end 
redirect_to routes_url
```

probably should be changed to something like below if you mean to redirect based on success:

```
if @route.destroy
  redirect_to some_other_path
else
  redirect_to routes_url
end
```